# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']'

Tags: php

I'm getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in your code on line 70

Line 70 is $message.

```
$random_keys=array_rand($lel,1);
$message[] = $lel[$random_keys[0]];
```

The whole code is here:

```
$message = array(); 
$lel = array(
    'Are you sure its the new year?', 
    'And i thought i was dumb', 'its not new year yet', 
    'LOL its ${date}', '...', '.....', '...', 'WUT', '.......', 
    'Ya drunk bruh ?', 'You sure you are not drunk ? what is 1+1 then ?'
);
$random_keys=array_rand($lel,1);
$message[] = $lel[$random_keys[0]];
```

Can we do it like this?

```
$message[] = $lel[rand(1,11)];
```

It still gives:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: Try to define `$message` as an array before it like: `$message = array();`

Comment: $message = array();$random_keys=array_rand($lel,1);
$message[] = $lel[$random_keys[0]];

Comment: it is defined as $message = ARRAY();

Comment: When you only return 1 value from array_rand, it shouldn't be an array response, but a scalar value (int or string depending on your array keys); so treating that value as an array and accessing entry 0 will only give the first digit or character of that int or string

Comment: @user3436939 Did you see my answer below at all?

Answer (score 4):

You are only picking one random key here:

```
$random_keys=array_rand($lel,1);
```

So you want to do this:

```
$random_key = array_rand($lel,1);
$message[] = $lel[$random_key];
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/PHWD8

Though, since you're only picking one random key, and one random message, do you even need `$message` to be an array? I'd just do this:

```
$message = $lel[array_rand($lel)];
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/jJKrG

As for your parse error, there's something we're not seeing in the code you posted. Perhaps it is some other surrounding code, or perhaps you modified the code before pasting here? In any event, you can see that your exact code does not produce a parse error: http://3v4l.org/Io1jc

Comment: $random_key is a better name for this variable

Comment: While correct, this doesn't explain the parse error...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I couldn't reproduce the error. I get: "PHP Notice:  Undefined index" when I run the code.